# Building C Extensions of Python(3.2) but get error "cannot find -lmsvcr90"

Tags: python, c

I am trying to Building C Extensions of Python(3.2) on Windows use distutils.
below is the code:(From Demo/embed/demo.c in the Python(3.1.3) source distribution)

```
/* Example of embedding Python in another program */

#include "Python.h"

PyObject* PyInit_xyzzy(void); /* Forward */

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* Ignore passed-in argc/argv. If desired, conversion
       should use mbstowcs to convert them. */
    wchar_t *args[] = {L"embed", L"hello", 0};

    /* Pass argv[0] to the Python interpreter */
    Py_SetProgramName(args[0]);

    /* Add a static module */
    PyImport_AppendInittab("xyzzy", PyInit_xyzzy);

    /* Initialize the Python interpreter.  Required. */
    Py_Initialize();

    /* Define sys.argv.  It is up to the application if you
       want this; you can also let it undefined (since the Python
       code is generally not a main program it has no business
       touching sys.argv...)

       If the third argument is true, sys.path is modified to include
       either the directory containing the script named by argv[0], or
       the current working directory.  This can be risky; if you run
       an application embedding Python in a directory controlled by
       someone else, attackers could put a Trojan-horse module in the
       directory (say, a file named os.py) that your application would
       then import and run.
    */
    PySys_SetArgvEx(2, args, 0);

    /* Do some application specific code */
    printf("Hello, brave new world\n\n");

    /* Execute some Python statements (in module __main__) */
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys\n");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.builtin_module_names)\n");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.modules.keys())\n");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.executable)\n");
    PyRun_SimpleString("print(sys.argv)\n");

    /* Note that you can call any public function of the Python
       interpreter here, e.g. call_object(). */

    /* Some more application specific code */
    printf("\nGoodbye, cruel world\n");

    /* Exit, cleaning up the interpreter */
    Py_Exit(0);
    /*NOTREACHED*/
}

/* A static module */

/* 'self' is not used */
static PyObject *
xyzzy_foo(PyObject *self, PyObject* args)
{
    return PyLong_FromLong(42L);
}

static PyMethodDef xyzzy_methods[] = {
    {"foo",             xyzzy_foo,      METH_NOARGS,
     "Return the meaning of everything."},
    {NULL,              NULL}           /* sentinel */
};

static struct PyModuleDef xyzzymodule = {
    {}, /* m_base */
    "xyzzy",  /* m_name */
    0,  /* m_doc */
    0,  /* m_size */
    xyzzy_methods,  /* m_methods */
    0,  /* m_reload */
    0,  /* m_traverse */
    0,  /* m_clear */
    0,  /* m_free */
};

PyObject*
PyInit_xyzzy(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&xyzzymodule);
}
```

I build the "setup.py" file like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

module1 = Extension('xyzzy',
                    sources = ['demo.c'])

setup (name = 'xyzzy',
       version = '1.0',
       description = 'This is a demo package',
       ext_modules = [module1])
```

and them I run the "setup.bat":

```
python.exe setup.py build -c mingw32
pause
```

and I got the error message below:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\桌面\C扩展python>python.exe setup.py bui
ld -c mingw32
running build
running build_ext
building 'xyzzy' extension
creating build
creating build\temp.win32-3.2
creating build\temp.win32-3.2\Release
D:\Program Files\DEV-CPP\Bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -ID:\Python32\in
clude -ID:\Python32\PC -c demo.c -o build\temp.win32-3.2\Release\demo.o
demo.c:8: warning: return type defaults to `int'
demo.c: In function `main':
demo.c:56: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
writing build\temp.win32-3.2\Release\xyzzy.def
creating build\lib.win32-3.2
D:\Program Files\DEV-CPP\Bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -shared -s build\temp.win32-3.2
\Release\demo.o build\temp.win32-3.2\Release\xyzzy.def -LD:\Python32\libs -LD:\P
ython32\PCbuild -lpython32 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-3.2\xyzzy.pyd
D:\Program Files\DEV-CPP\Bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.2\..\..\..\..\mingw32\bin\ld
.exe: cannot find -lmsvcr90
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\桌面\C扩展python>pause
请按任意键继续. . .
```

I can not understand what "cannot find -lmsvcr90" means?? And by the way,I use the  compiler of DEV C++.(Is it the problem??)

Can somebody help me ,Thank you.

Comment: Have mercy and learn how to format SO questions properly, please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

msvcr90 is the Microsoft Visual C Runtime. The [instructions for building on Windows](http://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#windows) only describe using Visual Studio; I don't know if it will work with dev C++. You can download free "Visual Studio Express" [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CPP).

Comment: thank you very much.I have solved the problem.I downloaded the VS2008 and found the file "msvcp90.dll" in the floder.Then I copy the "svcp90.dll" to the D:\Python32\libs,and run the "python.exe setup.py build -c mingw32" again,and I got the right result(pyd)!